# Finite Automaton to Turing Machine Example

Tags: finite-automata

I cannot seem to find an example of an NFA and Turing Machine that both accept the same languages. I am trying to understand how to convert an NFA to its equivalent Turing Machine and I think a simple example would help a lot!

Comment: NFAs are a special case of nondeterministic Turing machines, so I guess that by *Turing machine* you mean a *deterministic* Turing machine. To convert an NFA to a deterministic Turing machine, convert it to a DFA, which is a special case of a deterministic Turing machine.

Comment: An NFA could be deterministic (at any state there is exactly one outgoing edge for each alphabet symbol). Such an NFA can be interpreted as a Turing machine which always moves right, and halts once it reaches the end of the input.